# Image floating out of <main> element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have been trying to float a figure to the right of some text but the image keeps floating out.

### [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zkhK.png)

[Image floating out of borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa1uU.jpg)

I've tried fiddling around as much as possible but couldn't figure it out. When the page is at 100% zoom, the figure floats out, but when zoomed in, it fits right.

Sorry, I'm a newbie, not sure how stack works yet.

Comment: Semantic HTML elements like `<header>`, `<main>` and `<footer>` should, preferably, not be used to structure the page, they should be **strictly informative**. Use elements like `<body>` and `<div>` to structure your page, [they have different properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main). Please also read this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score -1):

You should add this to main element:

```
overflow: auto;
```

So main element will wrap around every child element.

Comment: This probably will not have the [desired effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), and the `<main>` element is a semantic element, and preferably shouldn't be styled.

Comment: I agree that main should not be used to structure the page, but it would work like I described... here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvmgtn1a/

Comment: OK, I agree, this will likely work.